# How to import Collada (.dae) files into Gazebo (ROS/Fuerte)?

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, blender, collada, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to import a COLLADA (.dae) file into Gazebo (from ROS/Fuerte) in order to run some simulations with the PR2. I created the file using Blender, and it basically has an environment (with some tables and walls) and cloth simulations as well. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to simulate this "world" in Gazebo.

I tried following this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_gazebo_worlds/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20world), but the "cob" part seems to be for a different version of Gazebo (not Fuerte); besides, step 5 leads to an infinite loop! I also tried changing the code from the wg_collada.world and wg_collada_world.launch as is recommended [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10899/gazebo-world-file-from-a-collada-file/) but no luck. Then, I tried [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/11013/importing-collada-meshes-into-a-gazebo-world/) too, but the [source paths](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/GazeboConfiguration) are not specified for Fuerte yet, so no luck there either. Finally, [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/11948/create-rough-terrain-for-used-in-gazebo/) didn’t work, because of the same reason as the later.

I would really appreciate it if anybody can help me figure this out.
Thanks,

Stalin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42529/how-to-import-collada-(.dae)-files-into-gazebo-(ros/fuerte)?/) by [stalinrios](https://answers.ros.org/users/3103/stalinrios/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use COLLADA models directly in Gazebo world files by adding them using the < model > tag like so:

```
<model name="small_wall_1" static="true">
    <link name="small_wall_1_link">
        <origin pose="0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
        <collision name="small_wall_1_collision">
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="small_wall.dae" scale="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="small_wall_1_visual" cast_shadows="false">
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="small_wall.dae" scale="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
</model>
```

This also has the advantage that you can specify them as "static" (as done above), which means no costly dynamics simulation will be performed on the models themselves. At least in earlier version of the URDF COB environments this was not the case.

The example was taken from the [go2011_arena.world](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/fuerte/hector_nist_arenas_gazebo/hector_nist_arena_worlds/worlds/go2011_arena.world) world file in the [hector_nist_arena_worlds](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_nist_arena_worlds) package which contains a model of the RoboCup German Open 2011 Rescue Arena made up of many small COLLADA models.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3